# How to use htaccess to redirect to www and https without having too many redirects error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm really stuck, as this is not my area, but I can get the following to work to redirect to www version, but as soon as I add another redirect to https (just bought the ssl and want to use it!) I get the "too many redirects" error.

This is what I have in my working .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^talbotandbourne.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.talbotandbourne.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

So how do I add a redirect to https as well?

Many thanks for any help received. I've looked all over the site for the answer to this question, and tried many suggestions from other posts, but I still get the error. I think I'm probably punching above my weight!

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting to `www`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^talbotandbourne.co.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://www.talbotandbourne.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and, redirect http to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.talbotandbourne.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was just what I was looking for!