# How to resolve the conflict between www and https redirect on .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to redirect non-www to www, and http to https. I am using this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^botway.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.botway.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

http://www.botway.com is redirecting correctly to https

https://botway.com is redirecting correctly to www.

BUT, when I type http://botway.com (so no https and no www, triggering both conditions) it redirects me to https://www.botway.com/https://botway.com/ (404 error)

You can test it live on the domain mentioned above. Any ideas on how to solve the conflict between the two Rewrite conditions?

*I already looked for similar questions on SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966951/how-to-use-htaccess-to-redirect-to-www-and-https-without-having-too-many-redirec)) but the solutions provided there are like the code I am using, and they have the same problem.*

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Sometimes the browser caches the URL, so try to clear your cache and try again.

Comment: Duh! It was the cache indeed. Thanks! What is the best practice in this case, close or delete the question?

Comment: Not sure. You are not the first person to have a caching issue, so maybe just close?

Comment: OK. I voted to close.